# Moving a Object in a specified road

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make this spaceship follow a certain road and when it hits a x and a y point of the screen that I specified its rotation is changed but it seems that the spaceship doesn't follow this road.

```
enter code here
 private void menuSideShipSetup() {
        menushiptypes = 2;
        arrivaltime = 4 * 20;
        Sideship = new Bitmap[menushiptypes];
        Sideship[0] = Utils.loadImage(root,"animasyon/ship_1_1.png" );
        Sideship[1] = Utils.loadImage(root,"animasyon/ship_2_1.png" );
        sideshipx = 0;
        sideshipy = 1920 / 2 - Sideship [0].getHeight() /2;
        rightsideshipx = 880;
        rightsideshipy = 1920 / 2 - Sideship[1].getHeight() /2;
        sideshipspeed = 1080 / 80;
        rotateconstantly += (135 - 45) / arrivaltime;
        sideshiprotation = -1;
        rightsideshiprotation = 1;
        rightsideshiprotationy = 1;
 private void RightShipMovement() {
        if ( rightsideshipx >= 880 || rightsideshipx  <=0 ){
            rightsideshiprotation = rightsideshiprotation * -1;
        }
        rightsideshipx += sideshipspeed * rightsideshiprotation;
        rotateconstantly += (135 - 45) / arrivaltime;

    }
    enter code here
    private void rightVerticalMovement(){
        if ((rightsideshipy >= 1260 )){
            rightsideshiprotationy = rightsideshiprotationy * -1;
        }
        rightsideshipy += (300/35) * rightsideshiprotationy;
    }
    private void rightVertical2Movement(){
        if ((rightsideshipy <= 320)){
            rightsideshiprotationy = rightsideshiprotationy * -1;
        }
        rightsideshipy += (300/35) * rightsideshiprotationy;

    }
    enter code here
    }
    enter code here
```

Comment: Does it even compile?

Comment: yeah it does, it's just a piece of the code

Comment: `rightsideshiprotation = 1;
        rightsideshiprotationy = 1;
 private void RightShipMovement() {` - This syntax does not look correct.

Comment: I made the below variable for y rotation and the upper one for x rotation.I am not having problems with the code because when I start the application it runs.Is there a way that I can publish the picture of the application as well?Since, it would  be easier to understand the question.

Comment: I suspect that you are using on older version.  Please the datetime on the `class` file

Comment: It's 27.06.2016 and the Android Studio version is 3.4.2

Comment: and what is the datetime on the java file that you have posted?

Comment: Also to make a correction the class is actually from one month ago but the java file is from 27.06.2016